# Volume of the surface between two given formula's

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Turn the surface between $x^2+y^2=16$ and $(x-4)^2+y^2=16$ around the x-axes and found the volume of that shape

My work:

$$x^2+y^2=16\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2-16=-y^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-x^2+16=y^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=\sqrt{-x^2+16}$$
And
$$(x-4)^2+y^2=16\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(x-4)^2-16=-y^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-(x-4)^2+16=y^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=\sqrt{-(x-4)^2+16}$$

The surface of between the given forumla's is given by:

$$2\int_{0}^{2}\left(\sqrt{-(x-4)^2+16}\right)\text{d}x=2\left(\frac{8\pi}{3}-2\sqrt{3}\right)$$

But from now I've no idea how to proceed?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've been given the equations of the circle of radius $4$ centered at the origin and the circle of radius $4$ centered at $(4,0)$, and you need to find the volume when you rotate the region where they intersect about the $x$-axis. One way is to think of slicing the resulting shape into discs perpendicular to the $x$-axis, with width $\Delta x$. The volume of these discs are $\pi(16-(x-4)^2)\Delta x$ for $0\leq x\leq 2$ and $\pi(16-x^2)\Delta x$ for $2\leq x\leq 4$. So our total volume is $\int_0^2\pi(16-(x-4)^2)dx+\int_2^4\pi(16-x^2)dx=\frac{80\pi}{3}.$